# Conversão de pdf para TIFF

Tags: pdf, r

Preciso converter um pdf para uma imagem `.TIFF`. Estou utilizando  ocódigo abaixo:

```
library(pdftools)
library(tiff)
convertidoTIFF <- pdf_convert(pdfTeste, format = "tiff")
length(convertidoTIFF)

armaz <- vector("list", length(convertidoTIFF))

for(i in 1:length(convertidoTIFF)){
  armaz[[i]] <- pdf_render_page(pdfTeste, numeric = T, page = i, dpi = 72, antialias = T)
}

writeTIFF(armaz, "C:\\Users\\flavio.matos\\Documents\\vish2.tiff", bits.per.sample = 8, compression = c("deflate"), reduce = T)
```

O arquivo que está sendo gerado é muito grande, pois o tiff vai para um software externo que não aceita imagens acima de determinado tamanho. Abaixo as propriedades de uma imagem aceita pelo sistema externo. Um arquivo exemplo tem, das propriedades abaixo, tem 85Kb, enquanto o que eu gero possui 751Kb

[image: Abaixo as propriedades de uma imagem aceita pelo sistema externo]

Há algum outro pacote que tenha gere tiff com a compactação CCITT T.6?